# configuring php.ini for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm trying to install phpmyadmin on windows. I get the dreaded The mysql extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.

I've looked for hours, and every fix I find causes apache to not start again. Here are my version informations.

> phpMyAdmin 3.4.10
>
> MySQL5.5
>
> PHP Version 5.2.17
>
> Apache 2.2.21
>
> Windows XP

I'm at wits' end.

Comment: Unless you're installing this all for purely academic purposes, why not use a pre-packaged install like WAMP or XAMPP?

Comment: I agree with nomaD, but if just in case you want to install it this way, you may want to uninstall everything and just start over. Alternatively, you may want to check if MySQL is working with PHP with a simple test (not sure if you've done so already). In terms of troubleshooting, start off with the obvious and check that the basic stuff is working correctly.

Comment: sounds good to me. I didn't know about the product. Thanks for the tip. I just dont care anymore, I just need to get my work done.

Comment: O M G... I installed WAMP, and still have the same error.

Answer (score 5):

In php.ini you must be missing this

```
    ;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
    extension=php_mysql.dll
    extension=php_mysqli.dll
    ;extension=php_oci8.dll
```

Note the un-semicoloned lines.

There are some good tutorials as well

[Apache Guide](http://apacheguide.org/apache.php)